# Nested Class in .h and .cpp files. How can I do it right?

Tags: c++, nested

I currently have two different classes. Let's call them `ClassA` and `ClassB`. And each one is divided into an **.h** and a **.cpp** file. I've decided that I need to make `ClassB` a nested class of `ClassA`. What is the correct and fastest way to do that without having to start from scratch?

Example:

**ClassA.h:**

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

#include "ClassB.h"

class ClassA{
    public:
        void enclosingClassMethod();
    private:
        int i;
        ClassB classBobject;
};
#endif // CLASSA_H
```

**ClassA.cpp:**

```
#include "ClassA.h"

ClassA::ClassA{//ctor}
~ClassA::ClassA{//dtor}

void ClassA::enclosingClassMethod(){//something here}
```

**ClassB.h:**

```
#ifndef CLASSB_H
#define CLASSB_H

class ClassB{
    public:
        void nestedClassMethod();
    private:
        int j;
};
#endif // CLASSB_H
```

**ClassB.cpp:**

```
#include "ClassB.h"

ClassB::ClassB{//ctor}
~ClassB::ClassB{//dtor}

void ClassB::nestedClassMethod(){//here i need to call enclosingClassMethod() 
                                 //and i need full class definition of ClassA 
                                 //to do that
                                }
```

I want to make `ClassB` a nested (inner) class of `ClassA` so that I can access `ClassA`'s data through `ClassB`

Comment: What do you mean "nested class"? As in a `ClassB` is a property of `ClassA`? Some code to illustrate would help a lot. Sometimes you can deal with this through forward declarations and pointers, sometimes there's a better approach.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. It is not clear why you think you would need to start from scratch.

Comment: @tadman `ClassA` has a `ClassB` object as a data member. I need to have access to `ClassA` functions inside `ClassB` functions. And I can't do that with just forward declarations. I need full class definition. So that's why I need to use nested class. `ClassB` needs to become "nested" inside `ClassA`.

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Long answer: A `ClassB` instance has absolutely no idea it's contained within a `ClassA` instance *unless you tell it* and back-reference that on creation. That's an inversion of control, though, the top-level object should be in charge and making the function calls, not some dependent structure.

Comment: I' ve found examples of nested classes but they were not divided into **.h** and **.cpp** files. They were a single file (declaration and definition combined). That's why I don't know how to implement nesting correctly cause in my case I have both **.h** and **.cpp** files already writen

Comment: If you have a java background, then consider class `B` as a static class. It doesn't have a reference to the enclosing object. You need to manually provide it.